# ModuleNotFoundError thrown on PySpark df.show() after running custom UDF function

Tags: pyspark, python-import, user-defined-functions

I am developing data transformation processes in Jupyter a notebook that imports code from other python scripts from a custom package in the repository.

My structure is something like this:

- notebooks

  - etl

    - `A.ipynb`
- src

  - `__init__.py`
  - data

    - transform

      - `B.py`

In `A.ipynb` I import `B.py`, initialize my spark session, add the python file to the sparkContext, register my UDF functions, then call a function that performs the transformation logic, inside of which the udf is called. I can run with no errors until I attempt to show the data using either

`spark.sql("SELECT * FROM _a").show()`

or

`df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM _a")`

`df.show()`

and get the following error:

```
PythonException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table").show(truncate=False)

File c:\Documents\repo\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:912, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    903 except ValueError:
    904     raise PySparkTypeError(
    905         error_class="NOT_BOOL",
    906         message_parameters={
   (...)
    909         },
    910     )
--> 912 print(self._jdf.showString(n, int_truncate, vertical))

File c:\Documents\repo\venv\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File c:\Documents\repo\venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:175, in capture_sql_exception..deco(*a, **kw)
    171 converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
    172 if not isinstance(converted, UnknownException):
    173     # Hide where the exception came from that shows a non-Pythonic
    174     # JVM exception message.
--> 175     raise converted from None
    176 else:
    177     raise

PythonException: 
  An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\AppData\Local\spark\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 814, in main
  File "C:\AppData\Local\spark\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 650, in read_udfs
  File "C:\AppData\Local\spark\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 375, in read_single_udf
  File "C:\AppData\Local\spark\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 87, in read_command
  File "C:\AppData\Local\spark\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 174, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\AppData\Local\spark\spark-3.4.0-bin-hadoop3\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 472, in loads
    return cloudpickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

Here is what I am attempting to run:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("../..")
from src.data.transform.B import *
```

```
import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf
from pyspark.sql.types import *

# custom function for spark configuration
conf = set_spark_config(env, pyspark.SparkConf())
spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local")\
                    .config(conf=conf)\
                    .getOrCreate()
```

```
spark.sparkContext.addPyFile('../../src/data/transform/B.py')

# custom function to register udf functions to the spark session
spark = register_functions(spark)
```

```
build_game_info(spark)
```

In `B.py`

```
def build_game_info(spark):
   spark.sql("SELECT ID, strip_chars_udf(score, expr2) AS GameScore, \
               FROM info".createOrReplaceTempView('_a')
```

Then error thrown here:

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM _a").show(truncate=False)
```

If I try all of this logic inside of a single Jupyter notebook I don't run into issues, so I believe I am going wrong on my imports somewhere. The `build_game_info()` function where the udf is executed runs with no errors, but when calling `.show()` the error is thrown, so I am unable to even verify if the function is working properly. If anyone can weigh in on custom udf behaviors with imports that would be greatly useful.